# Create Django pulldown with "Select" as the default choice?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I would like to create a Django pulldown that has the string "-- Select --" as the default choice.  When the user clicks on the dropdown widget, they'll see three choices, one of which they must select:

```
-- Select --          <= default choice visible
95th percentile       <= other choices
75th percentile       <= other choices
50th percentile       <= other choices
```

I've created a Django Student model and the associated Percentile lookup model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(User)
    student_percentile = models.ForeignKey(Percentile)

class Percentile(models.Model):
    # Contains "-- Select --", "95th Percentile", etc., etc.
    ranking = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ranking
```

The Student form is just a Django ModelForm:

```
from django import forms
from app.models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Student
    # Custom form validator for student form will go here
```

My idea was that I would create a custom validator in StudentForm that will check that the user selects a percentile ranking value whose index is greater than 1 since row one in the Percentile table's ranking column contains the "-- Select --" string.  Is this the correct way to implement this type of dropdown in Django?  I realize that I could create a RANKING_CHOICES variable that contains the rankings if I'd used a Django Form instead of a ModelForm and then had ranking be a ChoiceField.  However, in this case I'm using a foreign key relationship between Student and Percentile so I don't think that approach is applicable.  Although the approach I've shown works, it doesn't seem very "clean" to me as "Select" really isn't a percentile ranking value.

Thanks!

Comment: You could still attach Choices to a ModelForm with CharField.And insert (0,('select','select')) to the choices.

Comment: Absolutely do not put --Select-- in your Percentile model (see @srinivas-reddy-thatiparthy for alternative).  You may want to take a 2nd look and decide if you really need a Percentile model at all...also you may find if you keep it as a model, that ranking is better stored as an integer/decimal rather than a character string.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas.  And thanks Joseph.  Doing what I was proposing "smelled bad."  Glad you were able to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm)
    student_percentile = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Percentile.objects.all(), empty_label="--Select--")

    class Meta:
        model = Student
```

Comment: Thanks karthikr. This seems like a nice, clean solution that utilizes Django's ModelForm features.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list of percentile choices doesn't change often, this blog post gives a good method for doing what you're discussing.

http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

It describes using a tuple of choices and feeding it to a CharField (or perhaps per Joseph Paetz's comment above, you could use an IntegerField for more efficient sorting and aggregation, and so you're not storing what's really a numeric value as text).

With your case specifically, you could just add a '--Select--' option as the first option, perhaps with a value of '-1' or something similar, so you can validate on that value when the form is submitted.  If it's -1, they didn't pick anything.

```
PERCENTILE_CHOICES = (
    (-1, '--Select--'),
    (95, '95th Percentile'),
    (80, '80th Percentile'),
...etc...
)
```

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to that article.  I prefer Karthikr's solution in this instance but I can see myself using that article later on.